# How to automatically create sub-folder or immediate files in yaml file with python?

Tags: python, file, yaml, arff

I am writing a python code to do the machine learning problem by reading an arff file. 
Meanwhile, I want to create a yaml file to record each step of data generation process. The format is like this:

**Round1:**

```
-exe /exes/method
-parameters -a 1 -b 2
-input /data/loop1/data.arff
-output /data/loop1/train1.arff, /data/loop1/test1.arff
```

**Round2:**

```
-exe /exes/method
-parameters -a 1 -b 2
-input /data/loop2/data.arff
-output /data/loop2/train2.arff, /data/loop2/test1.arff
```

**Round n:**

...

The `/data/loop1` or `data/loop2` is the subfolder I want to generate automatically through the program. And I want to save the result arff file into the folder.

Does anyone know how to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For making output directory, try:

```
import os
os.makedirs("path/to/out/dir")
```

For writing yaml file

```
import os
import yaml
strOutFile = os.path.join("path/to/out/dir", "out.yaml")
objFile = open(strOutFile, "w")
objFile.write(yaml.dump(yourObject))
objFile.close()
```